# Select data from db via linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

let's say I've got a database with this table called cars in SQL server CE 4.0.

[image: table cars]

I would like to run a query in C# via Linq to select all cars where color is green and black. In this case, the table has only 4 columns with colors, but assume that we have a 30+ columns with color name.

I know the table design might not make a sense, but let's ignore this for now ...

I can run something like:

```
var cars = from myCars in cars
           where green== true
           && black == true
           select new { myCars.car, myCars.registration };
```

but how to make it more generic if the number of color columns increase to 30+?

Thank you.

Comment: It would perhaps be better to redesign your database and have a colour table, and then a many-to-many intermediary table.

Comment: yes, I agree, but let's say that the customer is stubborn and redesigning the database is not an option ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your assertion that redesigning the database is not an option, and you want to use LINQ, then I can see this becoming unwieldy and unmanageable pretty fast.

There is hope, however... have a look at [Dynamic LINQ](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation).  This should enable to use LINQ in an more arbitrary fashion.  E.g., you can now dynamically build the `where` expression part and have it accommodate as many or as few columns as you wish.  It would also allow you to easily extend it, should the number of colours increase in the future.

Comment: I agree with your comment on the question.